# # to %23 in c# on Xamarin ios

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a link in my C# code that directs the user to a website in MainPage.xaml.cs in my Xamarin program. The link works fine on Android but on iOS I get an error entitled;

```
Cannot GET /%23/signup
```

The link itself is

```
https://mystuff.simplifystorage.com/#/signup?_k=3vpcej
```

I have tried the following code but as of yet I cannot get it working.

```
string.Format("https://mystuff.simplifystorage.com/{0}/signup?_k=3vpcej", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#"));
```

Any ideas on what to do next folks? Thanks!!

Michael

Comment: If you need `#` as is, don't url encode it.

Comment: Have you ran a web debugger such as charles proxy? have you wrapped it in a try catch and read out all of the information there?